# Why can't I access constructor's value

Tags: javascript, constructor

I have the following code:

```
const PENDING = 0;
const RESOLVE = 1;
const REJECT = 2;

class simplePromise {

  constructor(resolveFn) {
    this.val = 1;
    this.state = PENDING;
    this.console();
    resolveFn(this.resolve.bind(this.val));
  }

  console(){
    console.log(this.val, 'this.val')
  }

  resolve(val) {
    console.log(val, 'val');
    this.val = val;
    console.log(this.val, 'this.val')
  }

}

const myPromise = new simplePromise(resolve => resolve(123))
```

In the `resolve` function, I am trying to change the value of `this.val`, but it seems that I cannot access it, whereas I can do that in the `console` function. Why is this happening and how do I get that `this.val` property out?

Comment: I think you want to bind to `this` here instead of `this.val`: `resolveFn(this.resolve.bind(this));`

Comment: Why is the context of `this` lost in this instance?

Comment: It is lost because you do not *call* `this.resolve` but instead *pass* the `resolve` method as a callback for later invocation. To pass the original `this` context along with it you explicitly bind it to `this` :) That's just how JS works.

Comment: When you bind to `this.val` (which is just the number `1`) then `this` within the resolve method points to `1`. So `this.val = val;` translates to `1.val = val;` which does not make any sense.

Comment: Ah awesome. Thanks for the clear explanation! Do you think I can use arrow function in this case to get the context of this without explicit binding?

Comment: Sure, `resolveFn(v => this.resolve(v));` will work as well.